# Force to use specific version of JAVA in centos

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

There are 2 instances of java version on my VM and I want to force to use java "java-1.8.0-openjdk" using shell script.

```
# sudo alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
 + 2           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-4.el8_5.x86_64/bin/java)
```

I tried below :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
java -version
```

o/p: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS

Help here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try again with this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
java -version
```

The difference in the the 3rd line. Added `/bin` to path.

If not working try (thanks to comment from @[Jeff Schallerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4957508/jeff-schaller)):

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
java -version
```

In your question you specify a very specific Java version. The java version are automatically updated when there is a Linux update.

**Fixing your Java version is bad practice.**

In folder `/usr/lib/jvm` there are a soft links to current JVM.
Probably `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0`

Suggesting to inspect the Java version installed in your system:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
```

In order to set `JAVA_HOME` to the current Java version.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
which java
java -version
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Now change the order to the `PATH` and test again:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
which java
java -version
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

There is difference in `PATH`. Hope you can appreciate the `PATH` mechanism.

Comment: tried both the approaches, however I am still unable to set the correct version. Do I need to do any other changes on my VM?

Comment: See my added answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your bashrc java path is override by another shell script's java path in somewhere. Print the $PATH and verify java 11 path is not included in there. If java 11 path also included in $PATH before java 8 it is override in shell script in somewhere.

```
echo $PATH
```

Check whether `$JAVA_HOME` variable in .bash_profile, /home/.profile, etc/.profile shell scripts. (Or else `grep` 'java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-4.el8_5.x86_64/bin/java' and find the shell scripts where the $JAVA_HOME configured by java 11 and it found remove those)

Then reboot the machine and try `sudo alternatives --config java` again